# Characterization of Closed Set using Metric

Tags: real-analysis

Consider a closed set $F$ and compact set $K$ where $F\cap K=\emptyset$.

Then, why is the following characterization using a metric valid?

Since $F$ is closed, for each point $x\in K$, there exists $\delta_x>0$ such that $d(x,F)>3\delta_x$.

Comment: What's the quantifier for $x$?

Comment: What is x? Is it in F?

Comment: That doesn't look like a characterization. It looks like a statement that turns out to be false for all $x\in K\cap F$.

Comment: @Gae.S. I have edited for clarification!

Comment: Since $F$ is closed, if $x\in K$ then $x\notin F$, so there exists $\epsilon_x\gt0$ such that $B(x,\epsilon_x)\cap F=\varnothing$. Take $\delta_x = \frac{1}{6}\epsilon_x$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you!